# React.JS - ComponentDidUpdate Method Does Gives Infinite Loop for Axios Calls

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

Good day,

I'm trying to fetch a new data once a new props has changed on my route.

Here's my sample routing:

```
<Route path={'/students/:selectedPage'} exact component={Students} />
```

Basically, I have a method that fetches my data. So I'm invoking it in my `componentDidMount()` Here are my sample codes:

```
componentDidMount(): void {
    this.getData()
}

getData(selectedPage){
    axios.get(`http://localhost:1343/students/${selectedPage}`).then(response=>{
        this.setState({
            students: response.data
        })
    }).catch(error=>console.log(error)
}
```

For my `componentDidUpdate` method which trigger if there's new changes in the `param` of my url.

```
componentDidUpdate(): void {
    if (this.props.match.params.selectedPage !== prevProps.selectedPage){
        this.getData(this.props.match.params.selectedPage)
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, it causes to have infinite request from the web api. Which makes the table laggy. I tried to create a state with a name, `hasLoaded` but it gives me an error message that says, infinite loop has detected.

Any advice?

Comment: looking at the code, that you have posted seems fine to me, `componentDidMount' should be triggered once and component should render based on state properties. However, you need to check the code (in previous component ) that calls this component, if that is making infinite calls anyway possible. Or show your routing, that can be helpful to detect the problem

Comment: Hi @MuhammadMuradHaider I added the routing with params.

Comment: this seems to be fine, check the button click or something, that leads to `Students` component, if because of that `componentDidMount` of `Students` component is getting triggered time and again.

Comment: Please check this condition thoroughly.

`this.props.match.params.selectedPage !== prevProps.selectedPage`

try `prevProps.match.params.selectedPage` instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compare your Props in `ComponentWillReceiveProps` like this,

```
shouldComponentUpdate: function(nextProps, nextState) {
    return nextProps.selectedPage != this.props.selectedPage ;
}

 componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if (nextProps.selectedPage !== this.props.selectedPage ) {
      //this.setState({ selectedPage : nextProps.selectedPage })
        this.getData(nextProps.selectedPage)
    }
  }
```

or Do this instead `Keep your selectedPage in state`

````
  static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps, prevState) {
        if (nextProps.selectedPage !== prevState.selectedPage ) {
            return { selectedPage : nextProps.selectedPage };
        }
        else return null;
    }

    componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
        if (prevProps.selectedPage !== this.props.selectedPage ) {
            //Perform some operation here
            //this.setState({ selectedPage : this.props.selectedPage });
            this.getData(this.props.selectedPage)
        }
    }
    ```
````

Comment: This works, but I need to double click the button to be able to trigger the `componentWillReceiveProps` method. I clicked the button once, but it doesn't work. I clicked the button twice, then it works. But it's not reliable though since the users need to double click the button to change the route.

Comment: The first sample code you shown is working but I need to double click the button to be able to refresh the table but it sent a request based on my browser network tab.

Comment: Try doing it in ComponentWillUpdate

Comment: it gives me infinite request loop in the `componentWillUpdate`

Comment: I put an alert box in my sample parameter `alert(this.props.match.props.studentId)` inside the `componentWillReceiveProps` but it gives me the previous parameter on the first click, then it gives me the desired parameter on the second click.

Comment: The first code you shown to make, is working now. Thank you!

Comment: Happy to help.  `shouldComponentUpdate` stops it from updating, if there is no change hence your first trigger gets eradicated.